# Is $A+B$ a connected set?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Let $A$ and $B$ two connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Is $A+B$ also connected in $\mathbb{R}$?
Then what about if it is in any space $X$?
I know that any connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval or any singleton set. It is obvious in $\mathbb{R}$. But how can I prove generally?
Please help me to solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by $A+B$?

Comment: What's $R$?  $\Bbb R$?  (Sounds like it based on your interval/singleton set statement.)  What's $A+B$?  $\{a + b : a \in A, \ b \in B \}$?

Comment: @ervx $$A+B = \{t : a \in A \ \land \ b \in B \ \land \ a+b=t\}$$

Comment: $A+B$={a+b:a∈A, b∈B}

Comment: Continuous functions take connected sets to connected sets. In general, your space has to have addition defined. If addition is defined and continuous then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 7):

The set $A\times B$ is connected, and $A+B$ is the image of this set by the continuous map $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$.

Comment: Namely, this holds for $A, B\subseteq X$, where $X$ is any topological vector space.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u\in A$, consider a continuous function $f:A+B\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. $f(u+B)$ is constant since $u+B$ is connected. Without restricting the generality, assume that $f(u+B)=0$. For every $y\in B$, $f(A+y)$ is constant, $f(A+y)=f(u+y)=0$. Let $x\in A$, you have $x+y\in A+y$, we deduce that $f(x+y)=0$, so $f$ is constant and $A+B$ is connected.

Remark that this proof can be applied to $A,B\subset E$ where $E$ is a topological vector space.